# PrimeNG p-checkbox - Add asterisk mandatory sign after label

Tags: html, angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-checkbox

Below is my `p-checkbox` code:

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
  <p-checkbox
    [(ngModel)]="allowParticipation"  
    binary="true" 
    label="I need to add red asterisk sign after this Label"     
  </p-checkbox>
</div>
```

How to add an asterisk sign after the label so that it should like below

(checkbox) I need to add red asterisk sign after this Label *

Comment: If possible  i can get Stackblitz for this, greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with CSS:

```
:host::ng-deep .label-required:after {
  content: " *";
  color: red;
}
```

and set `labelStyleClass="label-required"` to apply this CSS to your checkbox label.

See [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-checkbox-demo-okfdxt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Comment: Thanks.. any way possible by creating a specific class then adding it somewhere in html ?